# A generalization for martingales?

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am  a computer scientist interested in analyzing stochastic processes specified as probabilistic programs. In my research, I recently encountered an idea that looks just like a martingale, but is somehow more general. I wonder if these have been already studied and if so, can someone provide me pointers.

Let $X_n$ be a vector-valued random variable. Our "martingale-like" condition looks like this:

$\mathbb{E}( X_n \ |\ X_{n-1},\ldots,X_0 ) = A X_{n-1}$

Here $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. If $A$ were invertible, then $(A^{-1})^n X_n$ is a martingale. But in general all we can say about $A$ is that it is a "non-negative" matrix (all entries are non-negative).

Thanks,

Sriram

Comment: This is called a first-order vector autoregressive process in time series http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_autoregression  and is a Markov process. (note though that these are usually defined more generally than on the wikipedia page, which gives a restricted special case of independent errors instead of a martingale difference.)

Comment: If $A$ is primitive, and its largest eigenvalue, which is the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue, $\rho<1$, then $A^{-1}$ exists and then $\left(A^{-1}\right)^nX_n$ is a martingale.

Comment: $Z_n=X_n - A X_{n-1}$ is a martingale as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bob and Samrat. I know about auto-regressive moving average (ARMA) models: we ususally write $x_{n+1} = A x_n + r$ for some random variables $r$. We have an expectation here on the LHS and the random variable $r$ is unknown with mean zero and "arbitrarily correlated" with x_n,..,x_0.  Samrat's comment about Perron-Frobenius theory is very useful as well. Gives me some things to read up on. Thanks a lot again.